# cme options volume

Tags: options, liquidity, cme

I am lookin at https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_quotes_volume_voi.html?foi=O&optionProductId=3#tradeDate=20210312. It says about 16 million in options was traded. When I look at the https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_quotes_globex_options.html?optionProductId=3583&optionExpiration=3-U1#optionProductId=7407&optionExpiration=3-U1&strikeRange=ATM it shows most of the volume is close to 1. Are these options not liquid

Comment: The first link is very general. The second links refers specifically to 3 year midcurve weekly options. These are short term options on medium turm futures. As you can see they are not very popular.